# How can I programmatically update a custom field associated with a Client Id in Google Analytics?

Tags: javascript, php, google-analytics

I want to programmatically update a custom field associated with a Google Analytics [Client ID](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/field-reference#clientId). The custom field I want to associate with each Client Id, will be called "Leads" and it's value can either be "Sold" or it can be empty.

I want to know how to update custom data by Client ID; either via PHP or JavaScript. Is this possible with [analytics.js](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/) or possibly a REST api of some sort?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can programmatically push data to Google Analytics via Google's [Measurement Protocol](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/protocol/v1/reference).

In order to associate custom data to a client id you must create a [custom dimension](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/custom-dims-mets).

*Example code (PHP) pushing data to Google Analytics.*

```
// init curl handler
$ch = curl_init();

// replace these values with your tracking id and the client id
$trackingId = '';
$clientId   = '';

// set url
$baseUrl = 'https://www.google-analytics.com/debug/collect?v=1&tid='.$trackingId;
$url     = $baseUrl.'&t=pageview&dp=%2F&cd1=Sold&cid='.$clientId;

// set options
curl_setopt_array($ch, array(
    CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
    CURLOPT_URL => $url
));

$response = curl_exec($ch);

print_r($response);
```

I am still unsure of how to globally update that custom dimension for the client id, so I created an alternate question for that [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42457023/how-can-i-globally-change-a-custom-dimensions-value-for-a-client-id).