# How can I globally change a custom dimensions value for a client id?

Tags: php, google-analytics, measurement-protocol

For instance say I have a user with the client id of `9394923.23349243` and I have a custom dimension called `Lead Status`. I want to update the value of the custom dimension everywhere for that client id.

*How can I globally change a custom dimensions value for a client id?*

*It it possible to globally update a custom dimension associated with a client id?*

(it doesn't have to be a programmatic answer, it can be just general google analytics talk)

**Technical Information**

- I am pushing data to GA via the [Measurement Protocol](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/protocol/v1/reference)
- Wrote a script in PHP 5.6.29 to send curl requests

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need use custom dimension on "User" scope. After one setup this dimension it will be everywhere in Google Analytics with this user.